# Rails test environment doesn't migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, migration, automated-tests

[image]

Production, and development work just fine, but the test environment doesn't want to migrate.

Does anyone have any idea as to why the gem is not working for the migration?

Comment: I use `rake db:test:prepare`.

Comment: it still didn't work :/

Comment: Please don't include screenshots of code in your posts. Include all text in a human-  and machine-readable format.

Comment: this was not a screenshot of code...this was a screenshot of the error that I could not copy and paste over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up removing the repo, and deleting my database then re-installing everything which seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Did you run `bundle exec rspec:install` ?

In case you have multiple versions of rspec, you can try `bundle exec rspec` so it calls the one defined in your Gemfile.

Instead of `require`, try `require_relative`, that way, the path is resolved regardless of the location from which you're calling the script.

Comment: this did not help